# Procedure or function expects parameter , which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

> Procedure or function 'login' expects parameter '@Abc', which was not supplied

4 hours searching and trying and no use I already supplied this parameter (copy/paste) and the number of parameters given to procedure is the same of procedure and in order.

@Abc is an output parameter.

Stored procedure definition:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[login]
(
    @Abc int output,
    @firstname varchar(255) output,
    @lastname varchar(255) output,
    @Email varchar(255),
    @pass varchar(255)
)
As 
begin 
if not exists (select Email from user_1 where  email=@email)
 select @Abc = 0
 else begin
if not exists (
    select Email from user_1 where email =@Email and password = @pass
    )
    select @Abc = 1
else
select @Abc = 2,@firstname = u.first_name ,@lastname=u.last_name from user_1 u where u.email =   @email 
end
end
```

Code to call the stored procedure:

```
 myCon.Open();

 TextBox username = UserName;
 TextBox password = Password;

 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("login", myCon);

 SqlParameter count= myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Abc", SqlDbType.Int);
 count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

 SqlParameter fnp = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar,255);
 fnp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

 SqlParameter lnp = myCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
 lnp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",username.Text);
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password.Text);

 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 myCon.Close();
```

Comment: As an aside - please tell me you're not storing passwords in plaintext in your database.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and be cautious when using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @j.steen it is school project  not a real database

Comment: @marc_s thanks will search for it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have omitted:

```
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

So the command sent to the DB is a malfed `sp_executeSQL` call instead of the desired `exec login`

FYI there is also a shorter syntax:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Abc", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```